Solving coupled quartic ODEs
Good afternoon
I am currently trying to solve a set of two coupled ordinary differential equations and would greatly appreciate some help.
I believe that finding the solutions require the use of Elliptic integrals, but get stuck at solving the these integrals
The system which I am working with is:
$
\begin{equation}\tag{1.0}
\begin{cases}
Y^{\prime} = \left(2 \omega + R \right)\left(\frac{-1}{2}\left(2 \omega + R \right)R + C_{1}\right) - 2\sigma\left(-\sigma R - C_{2}\right)+2R \\
R^{\prime} = -2Y
\end{cases}
\end{equation}
$
where $\omega,\sigma,C_{1},C_{2} \in \mathbb{R}$ are constants
I progress as follows.
First I differentiate second equation to give such that the following occurs:
$
\begin{equation}
R^{\prime \prime} = -2 Y^{\prime}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}\tag{1.1}
\Rightarrow R^{\prime \prime} = -2 \left(\left(2 \omega + R \right)\left(\frac{-1}{2}\left(2 \omega + R \right)R + C_{1}\right) - 2\sigma\left(-\sigma R - C_{2}\right)+2R\right)
\end{equation}
$
which when carrying out some basic algebra for (1.1) gives:
$
\begin{equation}\tag{1.2}
\Rightarrow R^{\prime \prime} = R^{3} + 4 \omega R^{2} + \left(4\omega^{2} - C^{1} - 4 \sigma^{2} - 4 \right)R - (4 \omega C_{2}+\sigma C_{1})
\end{equation}
$
For brevity I then define new constants: $a = 1,b = 4 \omega,c = \left(4\omega^{2} - C^{1} - 4 \sigma^{2} - 4 \right), d = - (4 \omega C_{2}+\sigma C_{1})$.
Having done this I know that the solution structure for (1.1) will take the form of an elliptic integral
$
\begin{equation}\tag{1.3}
x -x_{0} = \pm \int \frac{dR}{\sqrt{18aR^{4} + 24bR^{3} + 36cR^{2} + 72dR + 36E}}
\end{equation}
$
Now upon having found (1.3) I am very stuck on how to move forward to obtain the solutions for $R$ and $Y$.

Solve ODE system numerically.
